# Fastest way to obtain web source with javascript in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, jsoup, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm currently trying to get the source of some page from android.

From pre-checking the source, it contains `javascript` in it.

In order to be able to parse it correctly by using `jsoup`, I had to do the following steps:

1. Load the url into a webView.
2. use `jsoup.parse()` on the `webView` to get the source with the `javascript` in it.

   ```
    wb_result.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    wb_result.getSettings().setSaveFormData( false );
    wb_result.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads( true );
    wb_result.addJavascriptInterface( new MyJavaScriptInterface( this ), "HtmlViewer" );
    wb_result.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

               wb_result.loadUrl( "javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                            "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');" );

        }

    } );
   ```

In my opinion, it is a little weird to have a webView in my activity and keep its visibility GONE and only to use it as a middle step in order to get to the source I need + it is slow.

I was wondering what is the fastest solution to obtain a source that contains javascript.

I read about Chrome Custom Tabs and that it should be faster but then I can't hide the opened tab from what I saw and it will disturb the flow of the app.

Specifically, the url im trying to get its source is - [link](https://merhav.nli.org.il/primo-explore/search?tab=default_tab&search_scope=Local&vid=NLI&lang=iw_IL&query=any,contains,%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A8).

Any modern ideas? all the solutions I saw are from 2016.

Thank you

Comment: I was commenting to you earlier...  I do a lot of scrape, but I have not used **Android Webview**, I have used a lot of others...  The solution that you are explaining - load a page into a `WebView` is the ***exact solution*** that I have read about from multiple sources... (But I haven't done it, I work on other stuff).  I would be really interested to hear if this "version" works out...

Comment: So lets hear about your version =)

Comment: Quote:  " I would be really interested to hear if this version works out.."

Comment: NOTE: Neither of your questions has the **URL** - which I would need to play around with it.  (It's what I said).

Comment: the version of using webView works fine until it gives status=500/503 errors. But still it is way to slow. I added the url.

Comment: I sit and wonder about **Android WebView** a lot, because it is one of the "versions of" **Scrape** that I haven't been allowed to try.  (They don't let me).  I'll look at the **URL** though.

Comment: Is that **Hebrew**?  My **Chrome** says "unknown" whenever it translates this page.